# Truncate CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, csv, truncate

I have a CSV file with 48 rows of integers.  I am using the openfiledialog feature of visual c# to allow a user to select this file.  I then want to have the program truncate that file down to 24 rows.  Is there a truncate function I can use to do this easily? If not how can I go about doing so? Below is what I have so far...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace sts_converter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int size = -1;
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                try
                {
                    string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                    size = text.Length;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(size); // <-- Shows file size in debugging mode.
            Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use only.
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good question, since I have found/learned a use for the Linq `Take` method.

Answer (score 5):

It could be as easy as:

```
string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
File.WriteAllLines(
    file, 
    File.ReadLines(file).Take(28).ToArray()
);
```

Comment: +1 using declarative coding-style is always more elegant and straightforward.

Comment: Easy, but not productive - it reads all lines to the memory, and only then takes 28. Try to imagine if there are 100000 lines. So what? Better to load line-by-line (use stream = File.OpenText(...) and then stream.ReadLine()) and just stop the loop after 28 iterations.

Comment: @Genius, no it doesn't read all lines. If you haven't noticed the [ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) method returns an `IEnumerable<string>` so it's gonna read as much lines as we actually take or enumerate (which is 28), so yeah, it's pretty productive. Do not mistake with the [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) method which reads all the lines in memory. The difference is crucial. So even with a file containing millions of lines this method will perform fast and consume as much memory as it would take to store 28 lines.

Comment: Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx): `The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.`

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. Darin is right - I mistaked it with ReadAllLines. This code is probably most easy and productive ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Call `ReadAllLines` to get an array of 48 strings
- Create a new array of 24 strings
- Use `Array.Copy` to copy the strings that you want
- Call `WriteAllLines` to write the new array to the file

(You can also use LINQ's `Take` method)